# Pygame Transitions/buttons not creating lasting change

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to create a game, where after you click the right answer, an animation occurs and the words 'congrats' or 'try again' appear. But, the animation is not working and the words only appear while I am pressing down on the button. How can I fix this?

I tried putting all the code in a while loop, but that caused the game window to not respond at all.

```
#Import Packages
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

#Initialize Package
pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode ((640,600))
pygame.display.set_caption("EduCAUTION")

#Colours init
crushed = (142, 71, 71)
white = (250, 250, 250)

#Images
math1BG = pygame.image.load('mathlvl1BG.jpg')
building = pygame.image.load('building.png')
skybox = pygame.image.load('skybox.png')

#Text init
pygame.font.init()
myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 50)
subtitle = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 25)
normal = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 20)

#Division Game text
divtitle = myfont.render('CAUTION with Division', False, (crushed))
divrules = subtitle.render('Click on the right answer to help the worker come down the building', False, (75,75,75))
divQ1 = subtitle.render('Divide 42 by me and you will get 7. I am..', False, (crushed))
divQ2 = subtitle.render('If you divide 30 by me, the answer is 3 doubled. I am..', False, (crushed))
congrats = myfont.render('Congrats!! Thats correct!', False, (white))
again = myfont.render('Try again!', False, (white))
opt1 = myfont.render('6', False, (75,75,75))
opt2 = myfont.render('5', False, (75,75,75))
opt3 = myfont.render('1', False, (75,75,75))

def mathGame2():
    xbox = 140
    ybox = 240
    win.blit(math1BG, (0,0))
    win.blit(divtitle, (80, 15))
    win.blit(divrules, (20,80))
    win.blit(building, (-220,80))
    win.blit(skybox, (xbox, ybox))
    game2 = 0
    #Level 1 ##########################################################
    if game2 == 0:
        win.blit(divQ1, (200, 200))
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        woah = 10
        #Choice 1
        if 200+100 > mouse[0] > 200 and 270+50 > mouse[1] > 270:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, white,(200,270,100,50))
            win.blit(opt2, (210, 270))
            if click[0] == 1 and click != None:
                woah = 0

        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, crushed,(200,270,100,50))
            win.blit(opt2, (210, 270))
        #Choice 2
        if 350+100 > mouse[0] > 350 and 270+50 > mouse[1] > 270:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, white,(350,270,100,50))
            win.blit(opt1, (360, 270))
            if click[0] == 1 and click != None:
                woah = 1

        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, crushed,(350,270,100,50))
            win.blit(opt1, (360, 270))
        #Choice 3
        if 500+100 > mouse[0] > 500 and 270+50 > mouse[1] > 270:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, white,(500,270,100,50))
            win.blit(opt3, (510, 270))
            if click[0] == 1 and click != None:
                woah = 0

        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, crushed,(500,270,100,50))
            win.blit(opt3, (510, 270))
        pygame.display.update()

        if woah == 1:
            win.blit(congrats, (200, 500))
            while ybox > 400:
                ybox += 10
                win.blit(skybox, (xbox, ybox))
            game2 += game2
        if woah == 0:
            win.blit(again, (200, 500))

#Main game Loop
run = True
while run:
    #Quit game
    pygame.time.delay(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    mathGame2()

#End Game
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete the answer of @Rockybilly, of course the variable `woah` has to be initialized before the main loop. Use the [`global` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=global#grammar-token-global-stmt) to access the variable in the function `mathGame2`.

But just as important is to do `pygame.display.update()` after the text has to be drawn to the display:

```py
def mathGame2():

    global woah

    # [...]

    if game2 == 0:

       # [...]

       #woah = 10 <----- delete 

       # [...]

       # pygame.display.update() <---- delete

       if woah == 1:
            win.blit(congrats, (200, 500))
            while ybox > 400:
                ybox += 10
                win.blit(skybox, (xbox, ybox))
            game2 += game2
        if woah == 0:
            win.blit(again, (200, 500))

        pygame.display.update()
```

```py
woah = 10
run = True
while run:
    #Quit game
    pygame.time.delay(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    mathGame2()
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This cleared up my problem entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You draw the ending signs based on the variable `woah`. And you set the `woah = 10`, every iteration of the game here.

```
if game2 == 0:
    win.blit(divQ1, (200, 200))
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    woah = 10  # Here!
```

So when you are not pressing a button, the `woah` is reset, thus not drawing ending signs. You have to set `woah` before game begins and not in the loop.